# Cast AnyObject? to [String:AnyObject?] always failing

Tags: ios, swift, type-conversion, swift2

Initially I had this code in Swift 2.1

```
func onSuccess(jsonData: AnyObject?){
    print(jsonData["message"]) 
}
```

After I upgraded to Swift 2.2 , I got an error such as

> Ambiguous reference to 'subscript'

for the line `print(jsonData["message"])`

I changed my code to this

```
func onSuccess(jsonData: AnyObject?) {

        let json = (jsonData as? [String:AnyObject?]) ?? ["":""]
        print(json)
}
```

However this statement is always failing because AnyObject? to [String:AnyObject?] type casting is not happening and getting the nil coalescing value. I want to type cast from `AnyObject?` to `[String:AnyObject]`. Is it possible?

Comment: post your JSON structure

Comment: The type `[String:AnyObject?]` does not exist at all since by definition all keys and values of a dictionary are required to be non-optional types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `Ambiguous reference to 'subscript'` because of your `jsonData["message"]` in the Swift 2.2 you should use `objectForKey` instead of ["key"]. In your case you should write your code like this `jsonData.objectForKey("message")` thats the your first question.

*Your second question answer is* Are you sure your JSON Data is a dictionary ? I think your data is an **array of dictionaries**. If i am right. You should *cast your jsonData to array of dictionaries* like this;

```
if let json = jsonData as? [[String:AnyObject?]] {
    for data in jsonData { // Enumerate the array of dicts to get value.
        print(data.objectForKey("message"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use optional binding like this:

```
func onSuccess(jsonData: AnyObject?) {
    if let json = jsonData as? [String:AnyObject] {
        print(json["message"])
    }
}
```

There's no good reason to declare the dictionary value as an Optional like `[String:AnyObject?]` since Swift dictionaries always return Optionals anyway.

This example was for decoding a dictionary.

Now if your jsonData is not a dictionary but, say, an array of dictionaries, you just adapt the type:

```
func onSuccess(jsonData: AnyObject?) {
    if let json = jsonData as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        for object in json {
            print(object["message"])
        }
    }
}
```

Etc.